# Pen Drive Bootable problem

Tags: live-usb, startup-disk-creator

When I am trying to make my pendrive bootable it shows an error "There is no enough space for this image" -using startup disk,I have also tried using unetbootin
but I am using a 32 GB Kingstone 3.0 datatraveler, I made other pendrives which are of 4gb live with the same application

what can I do to make it live ( or is it a bug )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it is because of a bug which is for usb 3.0 devices

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/1294877

hope that this will be fixed soon :)

Comment: Also one can use the unetbootin :)